# Replacing values in a nvarchar(50) column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, nvarchar

I have a column in my SQL Server table that is a `nvarchar(50)`. I'm looking for a way to replace values in the column.

So for example, This is my column with the original values:

[image: attached]

What I want is for each value to equal the following value:

[image: please see second picture to see the required outputs]

I can get this working with a replace function, however it then moves it to a new column for each value I'm replacing. Ideally what I would like is to have a single column with my new changes.

I cannot use the update function as I only have read access to this table.

Any info would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool, not SQL Server

Comment: "however it then moves it to a new column for each value I'm replacing" what does this mean? Data won't change columns unless you get your update wrong.

Comment: thanks folks, so what i mean is that it just creates a new column when i use the replace function, what i want is to have the changes on the one column

Comment: If you have an existing `select` query that you need to change, please [edit] and add that in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
create table MyTable
(
  Task nvarchar(50)
);

insert into MyTable (Task) values
('VLV LOADING/RELEASE 1st DS'),
('VLV LOADING/RELEASE 2nd DS'),
('VLV LOADING/RELEASE 3rd DS'),
('VLV LOADING/RELEASE 1st DS'),
('VLV LOADING/RELEASE 2nd DS'),
('VLV LOADING/RELEASE 3rd DS');
```

**Solution**

*Option 1*

Using a `case` expression.

```
select case mt.Task
         when 'VLV LOADING/RELEASE 1st DS' then 'Proximal Release Force-S'
         when 'VLV LOADING/RELEASE 2nd DS' then 'Proximal Release Force-L'
         when 'VLV LOADING/RELEASE 3rd DS' then 'Proximal Release Force-M'
       end as Task
from MyTable mt;
```

*Option 2*

In case the replacement values are available in another table, then use a `join`.

```
create table Task
(
  Id int,
  Task nvarchar(50),
  Description nvarchar(50)
);

insert into Task (Id, Task, Description) values
(10, 'VLV LOADING/RELEASE 1st DS', 'Proximal Release Force-S'),
(11, 'VLV LOADING/RELEASE 2nd DS', 'Proximal Release Force-M'),
(12, 'VLV LOADING/RELEASE 3rd DS', 'Proximal Release Force-L');

select t.Description as Task
from MyTable mt
join Task t
  on t.Task = mt.Task;
```

**Result**

```
Task
------------------------
Proximal Release Force-S
Proximal Release Force-M
Proximal Release Force-L
Proximal Release Force-S
Proximal Release Force-M
Proximal Release Force-L
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05e90f2baa9ac7a4621e9125d5442614) to see things in action.

Comment: i dont have admin access so i can only update the query, i cant actually update the column. would this work with the query results?

Comment: Oh, so you want to change the data in the result set and not the actual data? Like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57b0269356aa4b00f47a0b01877281ff)?

Comment: yes exactly sander, thats what i need to do

Comment: You don't need "admin" access to `UPDATE` a column. `sysadmin` privileges yet you do **anything** on SQL Server, @d_chawke , literally **anything**.

Comment: thanks Larnu, but i only have read access to this table, so the changes can only be in the query results

Comment: @d_chawke, answer updated to include the changes from the comments.

Comment: @sander thanks for that, however, is there a way to replace it? in your example you just added it start of the intial value, is there a way to replace the value entirely?

Comment: also, when i try doing that for two different values, it creates the column again, so they are not in the same column

Comment: I implemented what you asked in the question: `prox1 = newprox1`, so with a `new` prefix. A lot is possible, but update your question with more  _sample input data_ and _expected results_ if you wish to see any more changes.

Comment: you're right Sander, my apologies, i have updated my question now

Comment: thats perfect thanks so much for your help sander much appreciated